# javascript:; not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

Is there a way to get `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="function()">` to not be treated as a web address in safari? This works fine in chrome and firefox.  This is a shortcut for `javascript:void(0);`.  I dont want to have to replace it in hundreds of locations just for safari.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wr3ocjwj/

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have any code that is going wrong? Please clarify.

Comment: Here is an example [https://jsfiddle.net/wr3ocjwj/](https://jsfiddle.net/wr3ocjwj/), the first one does not work in safari but works in chrome and firefox

Comment: Why are you using a link in the first place? If you don't want to link something but do want a clickable UI control then use a button. That's what they are designed for.

Comment: I am making changes to an existing site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a javascript code that replace the "javascript:;" by a "javascript:void(0);" only if it's an iPad :

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_1_2/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_2_2/i.test(ua);
if (isiPad){
    var find = 'javascript:;';
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, 'javascript:void(0);');
}
```